# Svelte derived store not unsubscribing before component is destroyed

Tags: svelte

I have a component which contains a derived store which takes as it's input a store containing an array and returns the length of the array. Thus, this derived store can only operate on arrays. If the input to the derived store is null, rather than an array, the derived store will throw an error.

To prevent this, I wrapped the component in an if block to check if it is an array. However, it seems the derived store in the component is always run before the if block removes the component.

In what order does svelte process the if block and the derived store and how can I make sure the component is removed from the parent before the derived store in the component runs again?

Parent:

```
<script>
    import {writable} from 'svelte/store'
    import Component from './Component.svelte'

    const x = writable([1,2,3,4])

    function changeToNull() {
        x.set(null)
    }
</script>

<!-- when the value of x is set to null, the component is not destroyed before the derived store 
in the component runs again -->
{#if Array.isArray($x)}
    <Component value={x} />
{/if}

<button on:click={changeToNull}>Click</button>
```

Component:

```
<script>
    import {derived} from 'svelte/store'
    export let value;

    // dereived store to calculate the length of array.
    const d = derived(value, _value => {
        return(_value.length)
    })
</script>

{$d}
```

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/623ed906d45c4be0a0a3b92902272f61?version=4.2.3

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using stores in the first place?

Comment: Why not do the Array type checking from your `derived` function.

Comment: I suppose the sample is a simplified version of what you need, but I must say it is too simplified in the sense that doesn't transmit your actual need.  The sample can easily be fixed by dropping the derived store and working with the array directly in the value prop.,